# Joint density function - dependent variables

Tags: probability

I have an exercise which seems to be easy.
let $x$ be uniformly distributed on $[-1,1]$ and $Y = 1 - X$. What is the joint pdf of $f(x,y)$ and what conditions need to be satisfied in order that probability density function $f(x,y)$ exists?

So the pdf of $Y$ is $f_y{y} = \frac{1}{2}$ and $f(x,y) = 0.5$.
Now I am not sure, which conditions have to told.

Maybe that $ 0 < y < 2$ and $-1 < x < 1$?
Or is there something more tricky???

I would appreciate your help!

Comment: The joint density is not $\frac{1}{4}$, since the two random variables are not independent. The joint distribution is concentrated on part of the line $x+y=1$. I would say the oint density does not exist.

Comment: $f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $0 \leq y \leq 2$ and $-1 \leq x \leq$ 1 seem to be fine.

Comment: To sum up: the question is tricky, since joint density does not exist. Am I right?

Comment: @user160522 Yes you are right. There is no joint density. Formally you should say that there is no joint density *with respect to the Lebesguemeasure*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Observe that $P(X+Y=1)=1$. If there exists a joint probability density then
$1=\iint_{\{x+y=1\}}f(x,y)dxdy$ which is a contradiction since the set $\{x+y=1\}$ has zero Lebesgue measure.